# Additional input device to remove workload from hands?

Tags: keyboards, ergonomics

I spend a lot of my waking hours typing on a keyboard. Now I look for an additional input device, that would allow me to shift some work from my hands to some other part of my body, to

- remove strain from my hands
- allow me to type faster

I am a heavy emacs user and thus use a lot of keyboard chords, where I need to press Ctrl and/or Alt quite often (probably more often than any other key on the keyboard except for Space).

I tried pedals that are use for audio transcription (where the pedal is used to pause/unpause the audio recording), but those proved not suitable for quick on/off action. I need to have comparable speed to my left little finger, which I just measured to be at 5 press+release per second.

Does anyone have experience with any low-latency input devices that fit my requirements? I would be happy it if would allow me to control just one key.

Comment: maybe a stinky footboard. it should have no delay in it and minimun travel time. it also have 4 buttons